# Admob interstitial ads intergration error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, admob

I have the following code. I'm trying to integrate admob interstitial ads on my application. The code below is executing well and the application is also working well. However, I'm having a very big trouble after running the app. The app is exiting without throwing any exception. I have run the app without the ads and is not giving me such an error. Please help solve out this.

```
 private InterstitialAd interstitial;
        private AdRequest adRequest;

        public About_us()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;


            ApplicationBarIconButton menu = new ApplicationBarIconButton();


            menu.IconUri = new Uri("/images/menu.png", UriKind.Relative);

            menu.Text = "Menu";


            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(menu);



            menu.Click += new EventHandler(MenuBtn);

            interstitial = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-3870621720639923/4928477699");
            adRequest = new AdRequest();
            //Enable test ads.
            adRequest.ForceTesting = true;

            interstitial.FailedToReceiveAd += OnFailedToReceiveAd;
            interstitial.DismissingOverlay += OnDismissingOverlay;
            interstitial.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
            interstitial.LoadAd(adRequest);


        }

        private void OnDismissingOverlay(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            Debug.WriteLine("Ad dismissed.");
            interstitial.LoadAd(adRequest);
        }

        private void OnFailedToReceiveAd(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Ad not received");
            Debug.WriteLine("Ad failed to load!!!!");

        }

        private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
        {
            interstitial.ShowAd();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad received successfully");


        }
```

Comment: which sdk version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
      adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();